# (flex) How to make a part of a string in xml bold?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have all my string in a separate XML file and I am referencing it in my windowed application. I need to make some parts of the string bold, but I can't figure out how.

```
<s:TextArea text="{stringCollection.mainScreenText.text}"
                    borderVisible="false"
                    width="{mainGroup.width*0.9}"
                    height="100"
                    x="{mainGroup.width*0.05}"
                    y="75"
                    fontWeight="bold"/> //This makes the whole text bold
```

Setting a fontweight property sets the whole string bold. I need only part of the string bold.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add html tags to your strings (and probably wrap the strings into cdata so your XML is still valid) and use the textFlow property instead of text property:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import spark.utils.TextFlowUtil;
        [Bindable]
        private var text:String = "This is an example of <span fontWeight=\"bold\">bold text</span>";
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:TextArea textFlow="{TextFlowUtil.importFromString(text)}"/>
```

There is also a importFromXML function in the TextFlowUtils to get the contents straight from the XML

Comment: i tried what u said, it doesn't work. I have multiple text strings in xml and cannot select a child tag and pass it to importFromXML. it is expecting a XML and referring a child tag parses it as a XMLList. moreover I tried importFromString by converting the text from xml to string using toString(). it doesn't work either.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your XML or strings - if you try my example standalone it works. Try to debug and see if you are really getting correct strings with correct formatting. Maybe post your string example here or try that string with my example